# Should you allow users to change their account email address? How do you handle verification?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a client-server app. Upon Sign-Up, 4 piece of information is requested. UserName, Email, Password, Password Confirmation. Assuming the email has not been chosen, the username has not been chosen, and password/password-confirmation are equal and meet password requirements, the account is created.

A few questions...

1) Should you have a section that allows users to change their email? If yes to email, should you just allow them to change it without verification?

2) This leads us to ask... should email be verified upon original sign-up? My better judgement tells me no. The download-to-sign-up conversion rate I assume would be very poor.

3) If you allow the user to change their email in 1, should this free up the original email for another account? For example, Aaron sees sign-up is required to use certain features and signed up with a@a.com to speed along the process. Days later Aaron realizes he enjoys the app, and decides to change the fake email he used originally with his real one. He changes it from a@a.com to Aaron@gmail.com. Should the a@a.com email be allowed to be used for sign-up again?